# SQLite3 INSERT on iphone / objective-c, values not added

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite, insert

need help from some gurus here, I have a database which I have moved to the documents directory. For one procedure, I check if a table 'PASS' exists, if it does I delete & recreate it (just quicker). then I start reading data from another table 'EN', at the end of the calculation I attempt to insert values (ints, chars from the 'EN' table, floats) from both the 'EN' table and my own calcs

the procedure loops a couple hundred times and passes through the sqlite3_exec statement without errors.

But when I go to check the table it's empty (used sqlite manager addon for firefox)

the actual code is below, if anyone could spot the problem I'd be in great debt

thanks

```
sqlite3 *dbCon;                      
sqlite3_open([self.dblocation UTF8String], &dbCon); // open    

NSString *insert=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO PASS VALUES('%d','%s','%s','%f','%f','%f','%f','%f','%f','%f','%f','%f','%f','%f','%f','%f','%f,%f');",
    sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0), //id
    sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1), // type 
    sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2), // designation
    sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 4), // weight
    sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 5), //area
    d, // depth
    sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 28), // ix
    sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 30),
    cb,
    mmax,
    smax,
    stress,
    fb,
    shear,
    0.4*1000*yield,
    def,
    span/240.,
    span/360.
    ];

    sqlite3_exec(dbCon, [insert UTF8String],NULL,NULL,nil); // borrada
    sqlite3_close(dbCon);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEVERMIIND,

at the end of the NSString I have '%f,%f'  ~~> '%f','%f' fixes it

thanks!